# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/xml or type=text/plain when throwing an exception

Tags: json, jackson, glassfish

I am getting an Exception

> "MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/xml, type=class ..."

when an exception is thrown from within an application on Glassfish 4.1.

Before activation of Jackson instead of Moxy/Jaxb everything was fine.

Answer (score -1):

Verify if your MessageBodyWriterAdater is producing the same media type as your services/methods.

They have to be consistent or you just have to write additional MessageBodyWriterAdapters for unsupported types.

e.g.

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public abstract class JsonMessageBodyWriterAdapter<T> implements MessageBodyWriter<T> { ...
}

@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("xxx")
public class XxxBs {

    @POST
    public void create(@NotNull final XxxDO xxxDo) throws ResponseException {
        // do something
    }
}
```